# opt/local/lib/postgresql94/bin/psql: cannot execute binary file

Tags: postgresql, macports

I installed postgresql94 and the server via macports and when I try to `‘su postgres psql’`  getting following error...

> opt/local/lib/postgresql94/bin/psql: cannot execute binary file

Why is this? What is wrong..? I type my password correctly and then that error appears...

Comment: `opt/local/lib/postgresql94/bin/psq` -->> `/opt/local/lib/postgresql94/bin/psq` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from a user on #macports on irc.freenode.net

You need to run psql from a shell after running:

su -l postgres

To get a new shell running as the user postgres :)

And then it works!